# Assigning applications to multiple desktops (Spaces) across multiple monitors

Tags: macos, display, spaces, mission-control

I have a setup with two monitors.  Is there a way that I can assign an application to one space on monitor 1 and another space on monitor 2?  I currently have it set up so that each monitor has its own set of spaces and would like to keep it that way.

I use eclipse in a setup where I display the editor on one monitor and everything else (console, navigator, etc.) on the other.  Whenever I change perspectives, restart eclipse, or unplug the second monitor, the windows all move onto one screen.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the 3rd party application TotalSpaces2 has the ability to assign program's to specific spaces of Mission Control. Also, I know that you can use separate spaces for separate monitors in Mission Control.

So, check out the trial of TotalSpaces2 (for Mavericks) or TotalSpaces (for Mountain Lion) at http://totalspaces.binaryage.com/multi-monitors2

(I don't have a commercial interest in TotalSpaces2, I just started trying the program myself)